# how to do an optimistic update with injectEndpoints

Tags: react-native, redux-toolkit

How to create an optimistic update with redux toolkit using the injectEndpoints builder?
I have an api call structured this way

```js
import api from './api';

export const heartApi = api.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        createHeart: builder.mutation({
            query: (id: string) => ({ url: '/hearts', method: 'POST', body: { id } }),
        }),
    }),
});

export const { useCreateHeartMutation } = heartApi;
```

the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/manual-cache-updates#optimistic-updates) mentions that you can use `onQueryStarted` to optimistically update the cache of a request based on that mutation, however I don't know where to find that using the `injectEndpoints` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between using `createApi` or `injectEndpoints` here, in both cases it is part of the `builder.mutation` call:

```js
export const heartApi = api.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        createHeart: builder.mutation({
            query: (id: string) => ({ url: '/hearts', method: 'POST', body: { id } }),
            onQueryStarted(arg, {queryFulfilled}){
              // it would go here
            }
        }),
    }),
});
```